# Using Enum when querying cassandra with Datastax C# Driver 3.6

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra, datastax

I'm Currently trying to switch some MongoDB To Cassandra using C# Datastax cassandra driver (3.6), using LINQ expression to build the query with Table object mappings:

```
For<SomeClass>()
 .TableName(path)
...
 .Column(x => x.DataProvider, x => x.WithName("dp").WithDbType<Int32>().WithSecondaryIndex())
...
```

Thing is - some of the fields are Enums (Mapped to Int32) - while I manage to write them to DB using a custom TypeConverter, I'm having issues using them as query parameters due to the driver's serializer.

```
var mapping = new CassandraDBMapping(path);
var table = new Table<T>(session, new MappingConfiguration()
                .ConvertTypesUsing(new CassandraTypeConverter())
                .Define(mapping));
return table.Where(predicate).AllowFiltering().ExecuteAsync();
```

This could be solved by creating an Enum serializer and adding it to the serializers list on the driver, however, I'm looking for a solution without modifying the driver itself.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the same issue that is captured in https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-938

The user reported that explicitly casting the values to `int` in the query expressions is a work around for this issue until the LINQ component of the driver supports this.

Comment: Workaround worked for me, statically casting the enum to int before creating the expression:
```int dataProviderInt = (int)dataProvider;
expression = rt => (int)rt.DataProvider == dataProviderInt;```